# How to get a random number in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a random number from two values (min and max) that you can choose.
My code is returning a number that is bigger than the max value. What is wrong?

```
function random() {
var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
}
```

Inputs are:

```
<input id = "min" placeholder = "min">
<input id = "max" placeholder = "max">
<button id = "random" onclick = "random()">Random Number</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to cast the user-entered values to numbers first; `.value` returns strings.

`parseInt` is useful for that.

```
var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just parse to Int and use as below**

```js
function random() {
var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
//var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;

min = parseInt(min);
max = parseInt(max);
var random = ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
}
```

```html
<input id = "min" placeholder = "min">
<input id = "max" placeholder = "max">
<button id = "random" onclick = "random()">Random Number</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.random()
```

random from 1 to 10

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
```

random from min to max

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * parseInt(max) ) + parseInt(min) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect and also parse the number to integer before you calculate the values:

```js
function random() {
  var min = +(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = +(document.getElementById("max").value);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
}
```

```html
<input id="min" placeholder="min">
<input id="max" placeholder="max">
<button id="random" onclick="random()">Random Number</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the min and max values are string that's why you are getting unexpected result 
one of the solution is

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max/1 - min/1) ) + min/1;

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that implements [randojs.com](https://randojs.com). You'll notice that it's shorter, easier to read, and handles oddball situations well- like having a min that's greater than the max. Check out the site if you wanna know more about how it works or what it can do.

```js
function random() {
  var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = rando(min, max);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<input id="min" placeholder="min">
<input id="max" placeholder="max">
<button id="random" onclick="random();">Random Number</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```